# Is there any requirement of the number of master and worker in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to deploy a fabric network with five orgs(nearly 20 node including ca,order,peer) in a k8s environment.
k8s has three masters,so how many workers should i have?
Is there any requirement of the number of master and  worker
eg, one master at least has one worker in number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes v1.12 supports up to 5000 nodes cluster. More specifically, k8s supports configurations that meet all of the following criteria:

- No more than 5000 nodes
- No more than 150000 total pods
- No more than 300000 total containers
- No more than 100 pods per node

  Please check the official docs for setting up the large cluster [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cluster-large/)

Hope this helps.